# Google App Engine: Users API acting oddly

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I think I'm using the Users API incorrectly:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   user = users.get_current_user()

   def header(self, title):
     if self.user:
        render('Views/link.html', self, {'text': 'Log out', 'href': users.create_logout_url('/')})
     else:
        render('Views/link.html', self, {'text': 'Log in', 'href': users.create_login_url('/')})
```

**link.html**:

```
<p>
    <a href="{{href}}">{{text}}</a>
</p>
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I will click the "log out" link 10 times in a row, and reload the page, and it will redirect me to the `'/'` page. Then, mysteriously, one of the times I'll be logged out. Logging in fails in essentially the same fashion. What's going on here?

**Solved** - This works:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        self.user = users.get_current_user()

    def header(self, title):
        if self.user:
            render('Views/message.html', self, {'msg': "Welcome, %s" % self.user.nickname()})
            render('Views/link.html', self, {'text': 'Log out', 'href': users.create_logout_url('/')})
        else:
            render('Views/link.html', self, {'text': 'Log in', 'href': users.create_login_url('/')})
```

It looks like I can have instance variables by referring to them as `self.var_name` in a function, but never declaring them on a class level. Odd.

Comment: Is this actually one GAE or the dev server?

Comment: This is running on the dev server on my machine.

Comment: You need to use firebug or some other development console to see what's happening when you click 'log out'. It should redirect you to /_ah/..., which should send a Set-Cookie header to clear the cookie, then redirect you back to /.

Comment: @stefanw Even though one is declared at the class level, and another in a function?

Comment: if you declare it at class level it will be set when the server starts, I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the result of `users.get_current_user()` in the variable called `user`, but then your `if` checks the value of `self.user`, which is not the same variable.

Use the same variable name and all should be fine!

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I didn't include enough code initially. `self.user` is being checked from within a function, whereas `user` is stored at the class level.